# Subset data.table by column type R

Tags: r, data.table

Using R after a big gap.. I need to clean a large dataset, two steps in this process are :

1. Ignore/remove all non-numeric columns
2. Ignore/remove columns that have more than `x` % zero entries

What is the `data.table` way to achieve this?

I've been able to do the first part using `subset`:

```
subset(dat, select = which(as.vector(dat[, lapply(.SD, class)])=='numeric'))
```

but the same approach fails for the second part:

```
which(dat[, lapply(.SD, function(z){return(sum(z, na.rm = T))})] != 0)
```

Is there a `data.table` way of doing this in a single, simplified statement?

Comment: Can you provide representative sample data?

Comment: FYI, `... == "numeric"` is going to fail if you get a multi-class object such as `POSIXt` or similar in your data. Perhaps `inherits(., "numeric")` is better.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.SDcols`, see example below with `mtcars`:

```
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

pct = .5
dt[,.SD,.SDcols=function(col){is.numeric(col)&((sum(col==0)/length(col))<pct)}]

      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec  gear  carb
    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
 1:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     4     4
 2:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     4     4
 3:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     4     1
 4:  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     3     1
 5:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     3     2
 6:  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     3     1
 7:  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     3     4
 8:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     4     2
...
```

This removed `vs`and `am` columns because percentage of `0`s is too high.
If you take `pct=0.6`, these columns are kept.

Comment: If the `numeric` cols were removed in the first step above, would the 'with 0' cols be `integer`?

Comment: percentage of `0`s condition works on any numeric type : integer but also doubles. You can use one condition, the other or both.

Comment: and I misread non-numeric as numeric.

Comment: Not sure I got your last point. If you remove non-numeric cols, you can still get boolean, integer, double,…